# Convert .CSV file to .txt file using bash

Tags: bash, unix, csv, text

I have a CSV with lots of lines delimited by comma. I have to convert it to text.

```
66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 05:19AM,
66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 09:53AM,
66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 01:38PM,
```

I used command `cp source.csv destination.csv` and also `cat source.csv > destination.txt` but it does output in the same format witch each line coming in new one. It just gets appended together. It outputs like

```
66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 05:19AM,66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 09:53AM,66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 01:38PM
```

How do I make them to output each line in newline. Please help.

Comment: What do you mean "convert it to text"? It's already text! What's your desired output?

Comment: I want to convert it from .csv file to .txt file format..

Comment: mv source.csv destination.txt

Comment: use this : `dos2unix source.csv` and then `cat source.csv > destination.txt`

Comment: ".txt" is just a file extension, it only gives a hint about what the contents of the file are. You can change the extension simply by renaming the file. If you want to change the way the values are stored in the file, then you will have to show us what the desired output looks like. As @Taher has hinted, if you are going from a Windows system to a UNIX one, then you may also have issues with the different line endings these two systems used (`dos2unix` can be used to convert between the two).

Comment: Thanks Taher and Tom

Answer (score 0):

I hypothesise that the first block in your question is what you WANT, and what you actually HAVE is

```
66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 05:19AM,66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 09:53AM,66012523,39,Feb 02 2015 01:38PM
```

So what you want to do, I hypothesise, is split this up into separate lines.

Am I right?

This is a bit rough-and-ready but it works.  Relies on each group ending "M," and there being no other "M,"s in the text - which there aren't but I wouldn't call it robust.

```
sed s/M,/'\n'/g source.csv
```

Comment: Hi Mark, I just gave example text need not to end with M. Thanks.

Comment: Could you answer the other questions please?  Explain more clearly what you are trying to do.  Was my guess about what you're trying to do -- the file you're starting with and the file you want to end up with -- correct?

Comment: I was actually converting .CSV file to .txt file in UNIX so when transferring to DOS it was not recognizing newline character so as Taher suggested to use unix2dos. It worked for me. Thanks though for your help!